# Are Push Notifications limited and priced on IOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am currently working on push notifications on IOS, but I wonder how much push notifications are free and are there any restrictions from apple?

Comment: There is no charge but high priority push notifications may be limited and I suspect that if you send a very large number of pushes to a particular device rapidly then there may be some throttling just to protect users and the system from bad code/bugs on your side.

Answer (score 1):

According to this documentation from Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

> There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs.